# rails js/ajax updating div not properly updating with information

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

continuation: [Entry level javascript with rails: updating a div on form submit (3.1/jquery)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7932184/entry-level-javascript-with-rails-updating-a-div-on-form-submit-3-1-jquery)

I'm able to return 'something' now, just not what I want.

CONTROLLER

```
class ThisController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :js
def update
  #do stuff
  if resource.save
    respond_with(resource)
  end
end
```

VIEWS/RESOURCE

```
update.js.coffee
   $(".testdiv").text('<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial=>"resource"))%>')

_resource.slim
   p= resource
   p whhhhy
```

Basically, I have a form that posts remote (i.e. remote=true) that updates a db field and then the update controller returns that field. This form posts, the data changes, and when I change the text in _resource.slim the text will change....but the 'p= resource' does not get evaluated at all. I want the .testdiv to watch for changes made via the form.

So, I've been able to rig a minimal version one step closer to what I want....only I can't actually get variables to pass into the template. Closest tutorial I've referenced, but I'm not actually using the code, just trying to get a working ajaxy version within something I have that was already working.

I cannot see the problem atm, but it isn't right. I don't have access to manipulating the resource variable, but I am unable to. It seems simple enough (though I'd like to do with out a partial and extra files in views/resource, just put js in the assets/controller.js.coffee)

Comment: changed my variable from local to object (@), the previous controller just used a local, sooooooo, okay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comment, I changed the local variable to an object variable. This resolved the issue.